# Knockoutjs is not converting array into observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using this knockoutjs tutorial to convert array into observable array. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html. But the given following line is giving me an array of zero length.

```
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

Why anotherObservableArray is not working?

Comment: How are you accessing it to get the array of zero length ? anotherObservableArray().length should work

Comment: Yup Thanks.. I was thinking about the js array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access the underlying array for the length and not the observable array itself. 

`anotherObservableArray().length` will give you the proper length.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfSG8/

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us how you are using the `var anotherObservableArray`, but the following should work:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: anotherObservableArray">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

With knockout / js:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  this.anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

See [this jsfdiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMBay/).

Note that I'm not using a `var` to store the observable array, but instead creating it as a property on the view model.